# Create QuoteLine through CPQ API in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I am running into an error when trying to insert a new QuoteLine Item through Salesforce CPQ API model class.
Here is my code :

List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c> quoteLineTest = new List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c>();

SBQQ__QuoteLine__c newQL = new SBQQ__QuoteLine__c();

newQL.SBQQ__Quote__c = 'a108H000000i7BCQAY';

newQL.SBQQ__Product__c = '01t8H000002O0edQAC';

newQL.SBQQ__Quantity__c = 3;

newQL.SBQQ__NetPrice__c = 100;

quoteLineTest.add(newQL);

// Transform List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c> to List

List quoteLineModels = new List();

for (SBQQ__QuoteLine__c quoteLine : quoteLineTest) {

```
QuoteLineModel quoteLineModel = new QuoteLineModel();

quoteLineModel.record = quoteLine;

quoteLineModels.add(quoteLineModel);
```

}

QuoteModel quoteModel = new QuoteModel();

quoteModel.lineItems = quoteLineModels; // Assign quoteLineModels to lineItems

QuoteSaver saver = new QuoteSaver();

try{

```
QuoteModel savedQuote = saver.save(quoteModel);

System.debug(savedQuote);
```

}

catch(Exception e){

```
System.debug('exception>>'+e);
```

}

The QuoteModel and QuoteSaver class is the same as those provided in the Salesforce [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.cpq_dev_api.meta/cpq_dev_api/cpq_quote_api_save_final.htm).
The error that I'm getting is "exception>>ValidationException:[messages=null]: ["Attempt to de-reference a null object","(System Code)\nClass.QuoteSaver.save: line 3, column 1\nAnonymousBlock: line 22, column 1\nAnonymousBlock: line 22, column 1"]"

But when I am trying to insert the same Quote line through the dml statement (Insert) then there is no problem at all. Hence any validation rule isn't the problem.

Can somebody please help!